# English term for pre-thinker?

Tags: phrase-requests, expressions, translation

I was searching for an English translation for the German *Vordenker*. Basically a person, often a scientist, who began or further significantly developed a new concept or theory by contributing epoch-making publications or comments. Translation services give out expressions that have more the connotation of thinking about actual future events or things to me, e.g. innovative business ideas/products or future studies. But *Vordenker* doesn’t imply thinking of future actually, rather new ideas outside of current paradigms. Also *Vordenker* is in my opinion especially used in a historical or biographical context, as you can only judge his influence retrospectively (e.g. times cited). **A lot of scientists in German wikipedia are described as *Vordenker* in the first sentence while there seems to be no common english term in the english wikipedia.**

*Thought leader* has a too imperative character.

*Forward thinker* implies to me thinking of future itself.

*Key figure* is too inexact.

*Visionary* means someone with new ideas, which possibly never have come true in retrospect.

*Pre-thinker* sounds like awkward & uncommon English. Is there a better known expression? Or what would be a good one regarding above constraints?

---

**Update:** See how german.SE thinks about appropriate synonyms

https://german.stackexchange.com/questions/2337/whats-a-synonym-next-to-vordenker-vorreiter-freidenker-pionier/2344#2344

Comment: forward thinker seems the best match. you assert it has no future aspect, but "pre-" implies time. also "fore thinker" is (transliterally) "vordanker" is it not?

Answer (score 17, accepted):

*Pioneer* (often seen in adjectival form, as in "a pioneering scientist") is a reasonably close match.

But I doubt you'll find an exact analogue. A *pioneer* or a *trailblazer* does something first, and a *visionary* thinks something first, but I don't think we have a common word for someone who thinks and does something first, or someone who does something thought-related first. (In point of fact, when English lacks a perfect word for a useful concept, we often end up importing one from German: *zeitgeist*, *schadenfreude*, etc. Maybe we should start using *vordenker*!)

Comment: Related: "Innovator."

Comment: i very agree about importing it! Robusto answer made me think of *unerring explorer* as phrase for *Vordenker*. I think this fits Pioneer pretty much. Someone with overview and insight and knowledge what next steps are important to develop theories/knowledge further. **But both Pioneer/Explorer have more the connotation of a experimental researcher**, otherwise they would be perfect also of the biographical connotation pioneer has. "He was a pioneer", but never "He is a pioneer".

Comment: +1 I think *pioneer* is best; don't know why I didn't think of it!  Also, I am a big fan of loaning words from other languages.

Answer (score 8):

It sounds like you are looking for a word to describe a person who possesses **foresight** and **intelligence**.

With that in mind, you might look at *mastermind*:

> **mastermind** |ˈmastərˌmīnd|
>   *noun*
>   a person with an outstanding intellect: *an eminent musical mastermind*.
>   • someone who plans and directs an ingenious and complex scheme or enterprise: *the mastermind behind the project*.

Still, don't toss *visionary* on the scrap heap too quickly:

> **visionary** |ˈviZHəˌnerē|
>   *noun* ( pl. visionaries )
>   a person with original ideas about what the future will or could be like.

Usually the latter term is applied to people who were successful in grasping possibilities and bringing them to fruition.

Comment: foresight imho doesnt match, but insight and overview, **there is imo really no connotation of future in *Vordenker***, of course something new always happens in future, so this is a redundant connotation the term has not to carry. Having foresight, means he knows how things will happen, but a *Vordenker* knows what the important next steps are to further a scientific community/theory, basically he starts to found new paradigms. Imo *unerring explorer* would better match than *Visionary*, which imo is often next to sci-fi/fantasy in German. Mastermind i like much more +1

Answer (score 4):

The terms *freethinker* and *trailblazer* are excellent here.

[Freethinker](http://dictionary.reference.com/browse/freethinker):

> a person who forms opinions on the basis of reason, independent of authority or tradition, especially a person whose religious opinions differ from established belief.

[Trailblazer](http://dictionary.reference.com/browse/trailblazer):

> **2.** a pioneer in any field of endeavor: *a trailblazer in science.*

Both of these, especially trailblazers, are often not recognized as such during their trailblazing activities; many times only in retrospect do people recognize the value of their contributions.

Edit: I didn't do a thesaurus search, and therefore missed the word *pioneer*.  Suggested by @phenry, I have to say I cast my vote to that one.  *[Pioneer](http://dictionary.reference.com/browse/pioneer)* or *pioneering* is best.

Comment: +1 for Freethinker. To me it seemed the best noun for one who thinks outside the box about current paradigms.  Though @Hauser, as the provided definition suggests, this is more of a person who differs from the norm, not someone who necessarily expounds on existing paradigms.

Comment: +1 for trailblazer, seems best besides pioneer. Freethinker lacks the biographical connotation and historical weight of vordenker

Comment: as the definition suggests, `freethinker` has a more religious connotation, that is, the opposite of religiously dogmatic. Not a good fit to the OP's requirements IMO.

Comment: I have heard this term used a multiplicity of times, and I think the dictionary presents an inaccurately presumed connotation.  I don't implicitly trust dictionaries, just in case; and in this case, my experience overrides it.

Answer (score 3):

> Luminary
>
> `1.` A person who inspires or influences others, esp. one prominent in a particular sphere.
>      `3.` A person who has attained eminence in his or her field or is an inspiration to others: one of the luminaries in the field of medical science.

http://dictionary.reference.com/browse/luminary

You could say

> an early luminary in the field of medicine

Answer (score 2):

[Pathbreaker](http://www.google.com/#sclient=psy&hl=en&source=hp&q=pathbreaker&pbx=1&oq=pathbreaker&aq=f&aqi=g1g-s1g3&aql=&gs_sm=s&gs_upl=25570l29751l0l30927l11l11l0l0l0l0l1253l11261l6-1.9l10l0&bav=on.2,or.r_gc.r_pw.&fp=b62454da27284b07&biw=1016&bih=573) is another relevant word.

Comment: Or 'trailblazer'?

Answer (score 2):

Progressive:

> pro·gres·sive/prəˈgresiv/Noun: A person advocating or implementing social reform or new, liberal ideas.
>   Adjective: Happening or developing gradually or in stages; proceeding step by step.

This implies the person that takes the existing SOTA to the next level.

Answer (score 1):

You could go with the literal Greek: **Promethean**. It refers to the Titan [Prometheus](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Prometheus), but the word literally is (ancient?) Greek for "forethought". It has come to imply great creativity as well.

Answer (score 1):

Besides @phenry’s excellent suggestions, the phrase ***ahead of his/her time*** has very similar connotations to ***vordenker*** , although it’s adjectival rather than a noun.

Answer (score 1):

I would also add ***forward-thinker***.

It even comes from the etymology of ***vordenker***:

> vor- (“before”) +‎ denken (“to think”).

(https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/vordenken#German)

Or, ***forward-thinking***. As in, "He was a forward-thinking scientist in field XYZ."

It can be not only someone who thinks about the future, but also one who *pushes things forward.*